# Varien/Magento Form Validate does not submit or update status

Tags: forms, validation, magento

I have to implement a seperate login form for Magento (complete seperate on different page, inside Magento dir, without magento logic). I try to use the Varien Form Validate JS. The validation works great in beginning.
It shows all missing field errors, but after filling out the fields, on pressing the submit button, the errors still shown and the form does not submit. No Errors in JS Console
Here is my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="login-form" role="form" action="https://www.mydomain.de/ext/login.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control input-text required-entry validate-email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ihre Mailadresse">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Passwort</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="password" class="form-control input-text required-entry" name="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Passwort eingeben">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" name="submitForm" class="button btn btn-default">Show Data</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The JS Script:

```
    var loginForm = new Validation('login-form');
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the same JS as the Magento core login page? (i.e. `var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I also tried it this way, but it gives me the same result. It validates the form, but does not submit, when it is valid. It only submits, when its valid in beginning.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, on a very heavily modified site. Issue occurs across all form inputs - validation catches the error, but then after you enter valid data, the error messages do not go away and the form cannot be submitted.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, (form would validate but not submit). This turned out because we had removed scriptaculous/effects.js via local.xml file. Adding this back in caused forms to submit again.

Magento 1.9.3

Comment: Thanks, this saved tons of time. `validation.js` requires `scriptaculous/effects.js`.